# How to create a fixture where I could add a session?

Tags: python, django, api, pytest, pytest-django

I have my API and here I developed login and logout view. Now I want to write pytests and I have a problem, idk how to create fixture where I can make my user authorized and set some id in session(this is required for the logout).

I create new_user via fixture(to avoid working with my db).

**views**

```py
@csrf_exempt
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        if not is_data_valid_for_login(data):
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()
        user = authenticate(email=data["email"], password=data["password"])
        if user:
            auth_login(request, user)
            response = HttpResponse(status=200, content_type='application/json')
            request.session['id'] = user.id
            return response
        return HttpResponseBadRequest()
    return HttpResponseBadRequest()


@csrf_exempt
def logout(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        auth_logout(request)
        response = HttpResponse(status=200)
        if 'id' in request.session:
            del request.session['id']
        return response
    return HttpResponseBadRequest
```

**pytest**

```py
import pytest
from user.models import User

PASSWORD = "testPassword"


@pytest.fixture()
def user():
    return User.create(first_name="Name", last_name="Last", email="test@test.com", password=PASSWORD)
```